# Not able to unzip a file downloaded through FTP get() in Perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I am using FTP get() to download a zip file from the server in perl, but when I am trying to unzip it I am not able to do it, both through perl and manually(I am using & zip).
But when I am downloading the same file manually then I am able to unzip it manually using 7 zip.

```
$fpath = "filename";
my $dest = "dest";
$ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug => 0)||warn("connection not made");
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($dir);
my $zipName = $ftp->get($fpath);

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zipName);
my $extractor = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $zipName );
my $ext = $extractor->extract(to=>"location");
```

The size of the file is same as the server

Can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Please check [`SYNOPSIS`](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.46/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#SYNOPSIS) && [`When_not_to_use_Archive::Zip`](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.46/lib/Archive/Zip.pm#When_not_to_use_Archive::Zip)

Comment: Also use ftp binary transfer, https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#binary

Comment: @Сухой27 how to do this in perl ??

Comment: Call the method prior to transfer, `$ftp->binary;`

Comment: @Сухой27: it was stated that the downloaded file has the same size and that it can also be extracted with 7zip. So it is not a corrupt file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589234/not-able-to-unzip-a-file-downloaded-through-ftp-get-in-perl?noredirect=1#comment49248003_30589370

Comment: @Сухой27: you are right in that the file was manually downloaded when trying with 7zip. But it is stated in the question that the file size is the same. But the difference between binary and ASCII mode is that with ASCII `\r\n` might get translated to `\n` or back (depending on source and target architecture).  Since this would change the file size no such transformation was done in this case.

Comment: @Сухой27 I tried it with binary mode, it worked. Thanks, You can post it as an answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you're right and it is possible that OP didn't notice a few bytes difference in file sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If downloaded archive is corrupt, you can force binary transfer which doesn't do any of ftp translations,

```
$ftp->binary;
```

Answer (score 2):

> But when I am downloading the same file manually then I am able to unzip it manually using 7 zip.

7zip can unpack a variety of formats, while Archive::Zip can only do a subset, i.e. mainly the original ZIP format. I suggest that your file is simply in a format supported by 7zip but not supported by Archive::Zip. If instead the file in question would have been created by Archive::Zip itself then the problem is probably different, because Archive::Zip should be able to unpack files it created itself.

Comment: If I download the file manually from the server then then only I am able to unzip it using 7 zip and windows extract all also, but if I am trying to unzip a file downloaded through ftp then I am not able to extract it by any way.

Comment: The `unzip` command line program has about the same limited format support as Archive::Zip. On UNIX/Linux you can try to use the `file` command line tool to check what format your file has, i.e. `file filename.zip`.